# How to format args JSON to get SOAP response?

Tags: node.js, soap, protractor, soapui

Below is the code I tried:

```
fetchUserDetails: function () {
    var url = 'http://ldniguiapp02.eur.ad.tullib.com/matchbox-forwarddeal/services/RefDataWebServices?wsdl';
    var args = {'args0':
        {
            'mnemonic':'ttan',
            'postingId':'75655',
            'customerId':'180816',
            'organisation':{
                'customerId':'180816',
                'firmName':'POLITICAL.GROUP'
            },
            'userType':'TRADER'
        }};
    var defered = q.defer();
    soap.createClient(url, CreateClient);
    function CreateClient(err, client) {
        client.getUserDetails(args, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                defered.reject(err);
            }else{
                defered.resolve(result);
            }
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
    return defered.promise;
}
```

and the equivalent SOAP request from SOAP UI looks something like this:

[image: soapUI request]

How can I format args json so as to get expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You should transform your json in xml

Here you can do this online (to check/verify/test) http://convertjson.com/json-to-xml.htm

And off course there is an npm module that does just this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsontoxml

```
...
var jsonxml = require('jsontoxml');

var xmlArgs = jsonxml(args);
...
client.getUserDetails(xmlArgs, function (err, result) {
...
})
...
```

I hope this helps